# want to add two textview in a custom listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to add two textviews in a custom listview. It shows the data but not combined them. It shows as a different layouts.

This is the custom listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rollnoText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_stuadd_drawable"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stunameText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:background="#00dcdcdc"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:textColor="#b9dcdcdc"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rollnoText"
                />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is CustomAdapter class

```
public CustomStuDataAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_student_data, objects);
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView Roll_No;
        TextView Stu_Name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        LayoutInflater StuInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = StuInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_student_data, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        //String str = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.Roll_No = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rollnoText);
        viewHolder.Stu_Name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.stunameText);
       // System.out.println(stnm);
       // rno=getItem(position);
        viewHolder.Roll_No.setText(getItem(position));
       // stnm=getItem(position);
        //viewHolder.Stu_Name.setText(getItem(position));
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        return convertView;
    }
```

This is the main class

```
List<String> details = new ArrayList<String>();
studbhandler = new CourseDbHandler(this, null, null, 1);
            Cursor c = studbhandler.stuData(tbnm);
            c.moveToFirst();

            if(c.equals(null)){
                System.out.println("NO DATA");
            }
            else {
                if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        rn=c.getString(0);
                        details.add(rn);
                        nm=c.getString(1);
                        details.add(nm);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                    studlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.studentList);
                    ListAdapter stuAdapter = new CustomStuDataAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_add_student,details);
                    studlist.setAdapter(stuAdapter);
                }
            }
```

output comes as this
[here i want to combine two rows like first and second then third and fourth and so on...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9YtP.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots about what you see?

Comment: you need to create custom model class for your student

Comment: And also, you are not implementing the view holder pattern right, check this http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: I added a screenshot in the end. please click it and help me

Comment: It means i have to make changes in the following line of code

viewHolder.Roll_No.setText(getItem(position));

Comment: i have added the code in the answer review it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation:"horizontal" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rollnoText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_stuadd_drawable"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stunameText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="#00dcdcdc"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:textColor="#b9dcdcdc"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rollnoText"
                />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom layout Textview

```
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rollnoText"
```

Remove

```
android:layout_below="@+id/rollnoText"
```

TextView like as below

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stunameText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dip"
            android:background="#00dcdcdc"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:textColor="#b9dcdcdc"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rollnoText"              
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom model class like this,

```
public class Details {
    private String rollNo;
    private String stuName;

    public Details(String rollNo, String surName){
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        this.stuName = stuName;
    }

    public String getRollNo(){
        return this.rollNo;
    }

    public String getStuName(){
        return this.stuName;
    }
}
```

And change your `List<String>` to `List<Details> detailsList = new ArrayList<Details>();`

And your do while method should be like this.

```
Details details;
do {
    details = new Details(c.getString(0),c.getString(1));    
    detailsList.add(details);
} while (c.moveToNext());
```

And your `CustomStuDataAdapter` should start like this,

```
public CustomStuDataAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Details> objects) {
```

And in your `getView`,

```
viewHolder.Roll_No.setText(getItem(position).getRollNo());
viewHolder.Stu_Name.setText(getItem(position).getStuName());
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your model class first I assumed you are making it for student so name it to StudentModel :

```
 public class StudentModel
    {
         public String name;
        public String rollno;
        public StudentModel(String _name,String _rollno)
        {
           name = _name;
    rollno = _rollno;

        }
    }
```

Now your custome List Adapter Class

```
 public class CustomStuDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StudentModel> {

Context _context;
         private ArrayList<StudentModel> objects;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomStuDataAdapter (Context context,
                               ArrayList<StudentModel> objects) {
            super(context,0, objects);
              this.objects = objects;
            _context = context;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

        static class ViewHolder{
            TextView Roll_No;
            TextView Stu_Name;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           int viewType = this.getItemViewType(position);
            StudentModel item = objects.get(position);
            //  convertView = null;
            View rootView = convertView;
              final ViewHolder viewHolder;
                    if (rootView == null) {
     viewHolder= new ViewHolder();
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.you_list_view_row,
                                parent, false);

            viewHolder.Roll_No = (TextView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.rollnoText);
            viewHolder.Stu_Name = (TextView)rootView .findViewById(R.id.stunameText);

     rootView.setTag(viewHolder);

                    }
     else {
                        viewHolder= (ViewHolder) rootView.getTag();
                    }



             viewHolder.Roll_No.setText(item.rollno);
             viewHolder.Stu_Name.setText(item.name);

            return rootview;
        }
    }
```

Now how to call it :

```
 ArrayList<StudentModel> details = new ArrayList<StudentModel>();
    studbhandler = new CourseDbHandler(this, null, null, 1);
                Cursor c = studbhandler.stuData(tbnm);
                c.moveToFirst();

            while(c.isAfterLast() == false){
                rn=c.getString(0);

                            nm=c.getString(1);
                            details.add(new StudentModel(nm,rn));
                c.moveToNext();
            }

    CustomStuDataAdapter adapter = new CustomStuDataAdapter(this, details);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Tank you for the help. I made these changes but it gives a null pointer exception on this line of code

viewHolder.Roll_No = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rollnoText);

Comment: my bad change userTextMessageHolder to viewHolder

Comment: I made that change
i used this

userTextMessageHolder.Roll_No = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rollnoText);

is it necessary to change it to viewholder?

Comment: No its ok , I made a typo mistake you can user userTextMessageHolder.Roll_No and also change it in userTextMessageHolder.Roll_No.setText(item.rollno); too

Comment: yes i changed it everywhere
i also change convertview to rootview
and now it runs but it shows only roll number not name

Comment: did you change viewHolder.Stu_Name.setText(item.name); to userTextMessageHolder.Roll_No.setText(item.name);   ?

Comment: yes i changed it everywhere i also change convertview to rootview and now it runs but it shows only roll number not name. I used userTextMessageHolder.Roll_No.setText(item.rollno); and userTextMessageHolder.Stu_Name.setText(item.name);